# Question on C++ undefined behavior. Casting between uint8 and int8

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it considered undefined behavior in C++ to cast between a uint8_t value and an int8_t value?
For example consider this code:

```
std::uint8_t x = 255;
std::int8_t y = static_cast<int8_t>(x);
```

The goal with this casting is to interpret the value 11111111 (i.e., x=255) as a two's complement representation (i.e., y=-1). Is this valid in C++ or is it considered undefined behavior?

Comment: IIRC the results are implementation defined.

Comment: I am somewhat certain that casting (`static_cast` that is) between integral types is never UB. I could be wrong though.

Comment: FWIW C++20 will mandate signed integers are twos compliment so there will be standard defined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep. Until then it's implementation defined, but not undefined behavior. So it won't blow things up but should be checked. Arguably, when the type `int8_t` exists and it doesn't on non-two's comp. machines, you get the expected two's compliment behavior.